# cc avenue payment gateway not return value in to redirect url

Tags: php, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I integrate cc avenue payment gate way in my site. After this I checked with my debit card.
Then it worked perfectly. This moved in to the billing page and then in to the bank page.
After completing the payment it reterned in to the 'Redirect page'. But `$_POST["encResponse"];` contains no value

I checked my bank account the amount is deducted from my account. Also I logged in to my merchant account they says that as a pending transaction.

If any one know about this please help me. If I need to activate anything for done payment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to call CCAvenue to unlock your account. You are not getting the response because they din't provide you access of this feature. Make sure you have activated the working key.

For that goto CCAvenue Panel -> settings & options -> working key -> click on submit.

By default radio button is on Activate and you have to set on deactivate. See image below. It should look like this. If you don't have access ask your client to do this.

[image]